# Howto import iOS6.1 DocSets from Xcode4 into Xcode5

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, xcode5

on SO there are links which describe importing the iOS6.1 SDK from Xcode 4 into Xcode 5. What I additionally want is having the DocSet for iOS6.1 also along with Xcode 5.

I already made a copy from

```
/Applications/Xcode-4.6.3.app/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.1.iOSLibrary.docset
```

to

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.1.iOSLibrary.docset
```

but it doesn't get listed on Xcode 5's download preferences window.

Any ideas?

Background of my request (to prevent questions/comments like "Why do you want to use the old SDK and documentation, hey?"):
I'm still deploying my AppStore apps with iOS6.1 SDK, because I'm not happy with iOS7. Otherwise I need working with Xcode 5 for other reasons and I want to prevent using both Xcode versions 4 and 5 on my machine.

Thanks,
Konran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way other than to use Dash, it works with old documentation and others: http://kapeli.com/dash